# Removing escaped strings in Java JSON Object

Tags: java, json

I have a Java program that will dynamically build queries for ElasticSearch given some params. Currently, the way I have this built escapes the strings because the JsonObject as a part of Google's GSON library requires a string to be passed to append JSON.

The output from the below methods is the following:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "filter":[
            {
               "exists":"{\"field\":\"user_id\"}"
            },
            {
               "exists":"{\"field\":\"campaign_id\"}"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, the exists values are escapes and ElasticSearch throws a fit about this. How can I achieve this result without having the escapes strings?

```
JsonObject buildQuery() {
    JsonObject request = new JsonObject();

    // build the terms query
    JsonArray termsArr = new JsonArray();
    termsArr.add(buildFilterQueryForField("user_id"));
    termsArr.add(buildFilterQueryForField("campaign_id"));
    JsonObject terms = JsonHelper.createObject("bool.filter", termsArr);
    request.add("query", terms);

    return request;
}
```

Below is the code for the `buildFilterQueryForField(*)`. In this method, i've tried to use a regex to remove these, however this regex doesn't give me the result i'm after.

```
static JsonObject buildFilterQueryForField(String fieldName) {
    JsonObject builder = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject nestedObj = new JsonObject();
    nestedObj.addProperty("field", fieldName);
    builder.addProperty("exists", nestedObj.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", ""));
    return builder;
}
```

The end goal for this is the following:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "filter":[
            {
                "exists": { "field": "user_id" }
            },
            {
                "exists": { "field": "campaign_id" }
            },
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those escapes are required because you are actually embedding another json object inside the string value for the `exists` field. instead of using `addProperty`, you should be using `builder.add("exists", nestedObj)` just like you do elsewhere.